# Various WCF bindings and their endpoints

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-configuration

I have few questions about various `WCF bindings and their endpoints support`.

1) I just like to know what is service meta data? How a wcf service meta data look like? Can u post a sample of meta data? How it look like?

2) Service meta data can be expose by both MEX and `httpGetEnable` then when MEX play a key role and when people set `httpGetEnable = true` ?

3) I am not understanding what is difference between `MEX and httpGetEnable` endpoint ?

4) Various wcf binding. wcf support various type of bindings as below

```
basicHttpBinding
wsHttpBinding
WsDualHttpBinding
NetTcpBinding
NetNamedPipeBinding
NetMsmqBinding
WSFederationHttpBinding
NetPeerTcpBinding
MsmqIntegrationBinding
```

so tell me which bindings are supported by `httpGetEnable` and what is supported by `MEX`?

looking for great discussion. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the following links You will get informations regarding this,

[What was the difference between WSDL & Mex Endpoint in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522493/what-was-the-difference-between-wsdl-mex-endpoint-in-wcf)

[Understanding httpGetEnabled and Mex binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715982/understanding-httpgetenabled-and-mex-binding)

[Why do i need both mex endpoint and httpGetEnable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285717/why-do-i-need-both-mex-endpoint-and-httpgetenable)

**For binding and its full property visit the following link**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731172(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i like to know what are the bindings supported by MEX and what are the bindings supported by httpGetEnabled ?